# map<key,bool> vs set<key> to keep track uniqueness of a key collection

Tags: c++, data-structures, dictionary, set

I write a text file from a const list of strings and I need to avoid duplicates (the list contains duplicates) .Which of these data structure is better(in terms of performance) to use to track already written strings,

```
map<string,bool>
set<string>
```

Now how I'm going to do this is,

```
foreach(string in list)
    if(not found in map/set)
       write to file
       insert to map/set
    endif
end
```

Or else is there alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map contains no entries with duplicate keys, so there is no point in using `map<string,bool>`. This is irrespective of performance. `std::set<std::string>` or `std::unordered_set<std::string>` would do the job. Here's an example:

```
std::vector<std::string> word_list = ....;
std::set<std::string> word_set;

for (const auto& s : work_list) // loop over words in word_list
{
  if(word_set.insert(s).second) // attempt to insert: fails if s already in set
  {
    // insertion succeeded: write to file
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is a point in using `map<string, bool>` though it may not apply here. `map<string, bool>` may perform better than `set<string>` when you remove/re-add items because re-adding is just changing the state of `bool` and not re-allocating and re-balancing.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Good point, but calling insert, as in the example, avoids this re-adding. So the machinery is already there in the `set` interface, one just needs to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You might gain a performance improvement with `set<string>` because `map<string,bool>` needs to store an additional bool value, which has at least size 1. Depending how the allocator and std::string are implemented this might result in larger memory consumtion (think of allignment) and cache misses. Look here for [finding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) and [inserting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert).

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the option to use c++11 I advise you to use `unordered_set` as it should perform asymptotically better than `set`. If this is not an option, then use `set`. There is no reason to use a `map<string, bool>` for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need another container, use algorithms:

```
std::vector<std::string> list = ...
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end());
std::unique(list.begin(), list.end());

// alternatively, copy to your file without changing source vector
std::unique_copy(list.begin(), list.end(), std::ostream_iterator(out_stream));
```

Whatever you do, you get an **n.log** complexity for operations (inserting in the map/set * n items). A map/set solution gets you **2.n.log** operations for **2.n** memory ; using algorithms get the job done with **n+n.log** operations and **1.n** memory.